# Should I use "is" or "are" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a sentence like this:

The context is about repairing keys.

> It will let you know what keys are working properly and what are not.

However, Grammarly asks me to replace the second `are` with `is`, given the reason that the verb `are` does not agree with the subject.

But when I wrote `are`, I think it refers to `keys`.

Is there anything I'm wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not our job to debug software grammar checkers

Comment: ...but it ***may*** be that grammarly is programmed to assume ***what*** is always ***singular*** (which is obviously ***not*** true, as your example clearly demonstrates! ).  The cited text is "reduced" from *...what keys are working properly and what **keys** are not **working properly***.

Comment: And this is a good example of why English grammar checkers are not very good.

Comment: I think if it hadn't mentioned grammarly at all a question like this might well get closed as "Too basic / Lacks Research" anyway. Why would anyone think *What keys **is** working properly?* might be a valid choice of verb, if it weren't for grammarly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammarly is wrong. However, you should probably use **which** instead of **what** (and maybe you'll get a different suggestion from Grammarly):

> It will let you know which keys are working properly and which are not.